# Creating Groups from Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a list of universities and a second list of universities along with a number of coaches the two universities have in common.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'First School':['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Louisiana State University', 'Louisiana State University', 'Louisiana State University', 'Louisiana State University', 'Clemson', 'Clemson', 'Clemson', 'Clemson', 'Oklahoma', 'Oklahoma', 'Oklahoma', 'University of Southern California', 'University of Southern California'], 'Next School':['North Carolina State', 'Notre Dame', 'Louisiana State', 'Alabama', 'Oklahoma State University', 'Duke University', 'University of Missouri', 'University of Tennessee', 'Washington', 'University of Southern California', 'Syracuse', 'Texas Tech University', 'Hofstra University', 'Mississippi State University', 'Clemson', 'UCLA'], 'Coaches in Common':[3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The goal is to group the universities into families that share a certain number of coaches (in this case, more than 1) with each family. The families would include universities that are not listed in the First School column but are listed in the Next School column and share more than 1 coach in common with a university already assigned to a family. The universities that do not share more than 1 coach in common with any universities would be dropped. If a university has more than 1 coach in common with universities in different families, then that university would be assigned to the family with the university that it shares the most coaches in common. I'm not sure the proper code to get the output I need but I've posted what the output should look like. The output would be used to append a different dataframe.

```
results = {'School':['Alabama', 'North Carolina State', 'Notre Dame', 'Louisiana State', 'Duke University', 'University of Missouri', 'Clemson', 'University of Tennessee', 'Washington', 'University of Southern California', 'Syracuse', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas Tech University', 'Mississippi State University'], 'Family':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(results)
df2
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O7p3.png)

Comment: Can you share what an example output would be.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not really sure about what you need to do.
As a starting point you could try to use groupby to group Univ according to Coaches in Common.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Coaches in Common')#group by coaches
for key, item in df_grouped:
    print(df_grouped.get_group(key), "\n\n")#print the groups you have
```